# How to write condition in loop Foreach

Tags: arrays, swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var isShowingRestaurant = false

let posts: [Post] = [
    .init(id: 0, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mniam", imageName: "logo"),
    .init(id: 1, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi"),
    .init(id: 2, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi"),
    .init(id: 3, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi"),
    .init(id: 4, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi"),
    .init(id: 5, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi"),
    .init(id: 6, username: "asdas", text: "mniam mniam mn", imageName: "sushi")
  ]
}
```

How can I access  my variable, for example I only want to show post with image name "logo". I wrote post [imageName="logo"] but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `filter`

```
let logoPosts = posts.filter { $0.imageName == "logo" }
```

Answer (score 0):

following code will filter only an objects with `imageName` equal to `logo` and return a first one. Result type is an optional.

```
let logoImage: Post? = posts.filter{ $0.imageName == "logo" }.first
```